# setState doesn't update as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a ReactJS beginner and this is my code below.

```
for (var key in getContentState){
    var string=getContentState[key]
    if(highlighted_cols.includes(Object.keys(string).toString())){
        arr=Object.values(string)
        this.setState({
            uniqueValues : arr
        },()=>{
            console.log("update")
            console.log(this.state.uniqueValues)
        })
    }
}
```

getContentState is an object which looks like 
[screenshot of getContentState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo5Ir.png)

I am trying to update uniqueValues everytime the key is matched with highlighted_cols. highlighted_cols is selected by user which in this case either species or farmer as you can see in getContentState.

It works fine when user select only one column (species or farmer). But when user selects multiple columns (species and farmer), it displays unique values for farmer only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are overriding the state (`uniqueValues`) key by updating the state inside the `for` loop. Have you tried to update the state only **once**?

Something like:

```
let result = []
for (var key in getContentState) {
  var string = getContentState[key]

  if (highlighted_cols.includes(Object.keys(string).toString())) {
    result = [
      ...result,
      Object.values(string),
    ]
    // or result.push(Object.values(string))
}

this.setState({
  uniqueValues : result
}, () => {
  console.log('update')
  console.log(this.state.uniqueValues)
})
```

Comment: Would be nice to see a working example of it. But this looks like it would be correct, as the OP should not be setting state inside of a for loop. Everytime you pass through the for loop you are erasing any of the data that was there.

Comment: I solved the issue by using your solution! which is using .push and moving setState out of the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's due to some react optimizations, or, more simply, the state is changed before the rendering is complete and the ending state doesn't contains the first value. 
You should not call setState() inside a for loop.

I suggest you to prepare the new object that will update the state and then call to setState() after the for loop is concluded.

Hope this helps